# Make all text white inside .navbar-inverse in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Text inside navbar is not white.
How can I make all text white inside .navbar-inverse class?

I am using this css

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #05467C !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

but it doesnt work.

[image]

I could use

```
.navbar-inverse * {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

and it works, but it seems this syntax is not recommended:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share the demo or live link where you are facing issue so we can help in better way.

Comment: try using .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a{ color: #fff;}

Comment: The whole point is to make ANY text white inside .navbar-inverse, without enumerating every element in css. What about the title and Back text?

Answer (score 0):

They are probably links, so try adding following:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

you'll probably don not need important and maybe not bg color, but you have to share the code to get a precise answer.

Next time, I suggest you to use inspector in your browser to get the correct selector.

Comment: The whole point is to make ANY text white inside .navbar-inverse, without enumerating every element in css. What about the title and Back text?

Comment: Share the code with us, but you will have to enumerate every element in css because the bootstrap is using SASS to generate the CSS output and the one with most selector will be used, that's why your * is working and others are not.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has three selectors under `.navbar-inverse` which use a color that isn't white by default:

```css
/* Copied from Bootstrap 3's compiled bootstrap.css at line 4595 */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-text {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}
```

To override these, simply use those exact same selectors in your own CSS:

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-text,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

As for that blue hyperlink you've got, I can only assume that you've added that outside of a HTML structure Bootstrap itself recommends. You can probably get around that with the selector: `.navbar-inverse a`, but you'll need to cater for its `:hover` and `:focus` states too.

All in all you'll probably end up with something like:

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-text,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-inverse a,
.navbar-inverse a:hover,
.navbar-inverse a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: The whole point is to make ANY text white inside .navbar-inverse, without enumerating every element in css. What about the title and Back text?

Comment: @monstro this should cover all situations if your HTML has the correct class names Bootstrap recommends.